# Start a ssh login shell using existing connection

Tags: c, linux, shell, sockets, ssh

My application has an existing ssh connection to a remote server. This application has an socket on the localhost. How can I start a login shell using this existing connection, simular to

```
ssh user@host
```

does.
Of course my application has to use some api when a program connects to the socket and wants to start a remote shell. (I can use The Secure Shell (SSH) Transport Layer Protocol https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4253 for that), thats not the problem. My problem is how to redirect stdin and stdout and stderr from the terminal/konsole to the socket.
Can someone give a hint about that? Thanks in advance.

(I have an fuse fs which provides sftp access to different folders on the server, it would be awesome when it can also offer terminal access to the server and possibly a chat session using ssh-chat... user has toc click on a desktop file my fuse fs provides, and the right program is started to make the connection to socket and start the terminal. This of course only works in a graphical environment)

Comment: Do you talk about ssh connection multiplexing?

Comment: @ Ctx. Yes. I want to use one ssh connection for more channels. One for sftp, one for shell access and maybe more.

Comment: You should ask a specific question for a particular problem. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."*

Comment: Huh?? My question "My problem is how to redirect stdin and stdout and stderr from the terminal/konsole to the socket." is abstract?? It's concrete enough I think. Having a socket, for example /run/example/sock, and how can I redirect the stdin and stdout of a terminal to it?